# How to test the app for this scenario?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5

I have an app which has scoring and other information stored in a database. 
The database is in the Library/Caches directory.

Now, we are making changes so that the database will be in the Documents directory.

For new users, there is no issue, but for existing users, the existing database will be moved from Library/Caches to the Documents directory, if such DB exists.

I want to test this for existing users. I created a DB and inserted scores and other info. Without submitting the app to the App Store, how do I put updated code into the device so as to test the existing users scenario?

I am not allowed to install ad hoc if there is already an app on the device.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you talking about doing testing on your own devices? If so, why not just run the old version (you do have the older version's code, right?), populate the Library/Caches database, and then run the new version and see if it deals with the old data correctly.

Comment: I need to give this to client for testing and for that I will have to create an adhoc. And as I said, if there is already an app on device, then it wont allow to install that adhoc. What should be done in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a duplicate of this question:

[iPhone App:Test the newer version of app first and after make it available for other users for download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938118/iphone-apptest-the-newer-version-of-app-first-and-after-make-it-available-for-o/8939446#8939446)

The short answer is, download the app from the app store, run it, and then install your new version over the top of it using Xcode. This will be the same as if a user upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Change the bundle identifier of the app and do a new adHoc build (you may need to create certificates and distribution profiles) - it will be treated as a different app and can be installed on a device with the previous version.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But what I want is to OVERWRITE existing app on the device. What do you think we can do in that case?

Comment: If you want to overwrite the app, can't you delete it first then?

Comment: No, that is not possible as we want to test a scenario for existing users. (transfering existing database from Library/Caches to Documents)

Comment: Then can't you just fake it? Prepare the new version of the app with the database in the old place and observe how it behaves on the first run.