# iPhone App:Test the newer version of app first and after make it available for other users for download

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, itunes

I have an iPhone App which is available on App Store.

Now I have made some changes in my existing App which can be tested only when an App is available on App Store.

So I want to release newer version but I want to test it first before it it available on App  Store for all users

And once it is tested and if it works fine as per expectation then only I want to make it available for other user.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The short answer is: NO** - there is no way to make an app available on the app store that only you can download and test.

If you can specify exactly what it is that you are trying to test that only works when the app is live, we may be able to suggest a different approach.

**EDIT:** if you just want to test the upgrade process, you can just install the new version on top of the old one - there's no need to delete the one already on the phone. For example if you download the version from the `app store`, run it, and then build and install a version from `Xcode`, it will install on top of the `app store` version, and keep all the settings and documents from that version, just like if a user was upgrading.

Also read up on "`wireless distribution`" for `adhoc apps`. Using wireless distribution, you can download and install the app from a link on your phone, just as if you were doing it from the app store, except the link will only work for `UDIDs` that were included in the `adhoc profile`.

Comment: here in my case I have created my project with base SDK 4.3 and my iPad has ios5 so i can't connect my iPad to my xcod.  and if I upgrade my xcode to version 4.2(with base sdk 5.0 with ios 5 support) from current version 4.0  and trying to run my app on my iPad some functionality is not working properly (wich works fine if i create an adhoc from xcode 4.0 and run it on my iPad )  in this situation what i should do?

Comment: So the problem is that on iOS 4.3 your app works ok, when compiled against iOS 5 it shows a problem?

Comment: Why not just upgrade your Xcode and update your base SDK to 5.0? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Two choices:

### OTA AdHoc Distribution

Set up over-the-air Ad Hoc distribution. These guys can help: https://testflightapp.com/

A user can install an adhoc build over an appstore build without deleting data, and vice-versa.

### Side-by-side Builds

Ok, so your question is about side-by-side installation: you want a user to have the real app and a test version on the phone at the same time. To do that you just need to create version of the app with a different bundle Id. So if your app is com.myco.MyApp, create a copy of it as com.myco.testing.MyApp. Then use Ad Hoc distribution (or whatever) to get it to testers.

I've got a build script that updates the bundle version with the build number. I'm actually just about to update the script so that it will modify the bundle Id so I can have side-by-side testing. This is what I do for the bundle version on my build server:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion '${PROJECTBUNDLEVERSION}'" $PROJECT/Info.plist
```

Presumably can do something similar for the CFBundleID:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleIdentifier '${PROJECTTESTBUNDLEID}'" $PROJECT/Info.plist
```

Comment: Ya I know about adhoc distribution but problem is that if already one adhoc is installed on device I am not able to installed the other without deleting and i want test the app in such a scenario as i am installing upgraded  version of app

Comment: Ah, right. Well then you need to create an app with a different Bundle Id.

Comment: I dont want to run app side by side if I change the bundle id the app will installed as different app and dont overwrite the existing app. So document directory and library directory will be different for both app .

Comment: A documents folder is part of the App. Even if Apple allowed you to install two different versions of the same app, they'd still have different document folders. Sorry. However, what do you mean "I am not able to installed the other without deleting"? An AdHoc version of an app can upgrade an app-store version and keep the data, and vice-versa.